# Does flex not support hashmaps?

Tags: java, apache-flex, hashmap

I have a Flex object which collects a DTO from the server. All the fields arrive filled in correctly except for the one that is a HashMap. It arrives as null.
I've tried giving it a type of both ArrayCollection and Dictionary, but that hasn't fixed it.

Does anyone know if there's an inherent incomaptability between Java HashMap and Flex?

If not, what might I be doing wrong here?  I'm looking at my jboss console and I see the data being populated correctly in the server side before delivery to the client. However, as it gets to the client, that field is null. I'm ready to kill myself.

Comment: I'm not going to put this as an answer because I am unsure, but what happens if you try to type it as an object? Hashmaps are basically just key value pairs, which is what public properties on an object are.  The biggest difference is with java you can strictly type the values and make sure that they are all the same type and you can use things besides strings as keys like a dictionary, but as long as you are just using string keys, it should work.  In ColdFusion, structures are like hashmaps and they come over as objects.

Also, don't kill yourself. Especially over something like this.

Comment: I hope that Scott adds your paragraph to his answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What about trying type `'Object'` ?

Comment: GOD, I wish I could uptick your answer 20 or 30 more times.
THANKS!

Comment: Please quote Ryan's paragraph in your answer. You're both right, but he details the reason why, which makes for good bathroom reading.

Answer (score 9):

It does look like object is what you want: http://www.mail-archive.com/flexcoders@yahoogroups.com/msg17137.html

Relevant text:

> When a HashMap is sent back to Flex it
>   will simply be an Object.  You can
>   access a value by doing myObj[key]
>
> Matt
>
> From: flexcoders@yahoogroups.com
>   [mailto:flexcoders@yahoogroups.com] On
>   Behalf Of prasanthasi Sent: Saturday,
>   November 26, 2005 7:24 PM To:
>   flexcoders@yahoogroups.com Subject:
>   [flexcoders] Mapping Java HashMap to
>   Flex Actionscript
>
> Hi,    I am trying map Java HashMap to
>   Flex Actionscript.  I have tried
>   Object mapping and Arrays with
>   Associative keys.  Nothing worked for
>   some reason.  Please post a sample
>   code if anyone knows how to do this.

Another possibly relevant link: http://www.nabble.com/How-to-deal-with-a-java.util.HashMap-in-flex-td17642614.html

Answer (score 0):

You want to use "Object" as per the Blaze DS "data serialization" documentation:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/blazeds_devguide/serialize_data_3.html#304283